# How to get a certain value from a text file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I want to get a value from an API. However I am unable to tell Python what I want to do.

This is my current code:

```
response = requests.get('https://sms-service-online.com/api/getServicesAndCost/?country=0&operator=any&lang=en')
data = response.json()
plain = data["data"]
```

However the data which I want to display in my script is in the ["data"] part of the json. It is kind of a json inside a json.

For example: with

```
print(plain)
```

I would recieve this data:

```
[{"cost":"0.45","id":0,"servise":"VK.com","serviseImg":"bg-vk","number":"Numbers: 3047","value":"vk"},{"cost":"0.07","id":1,"servise":"OK.ru","serviseImg":"bg-ok","number":"Numbers: 14397","value":"ok"},{"cost":"0.15","id":2,"servise":"Whatsapp","serviseImg":"bg-wa","number":"Numbers: 17610","value":"wa"},{"cost":"0.18","id":3,"servise":"Viber","serviseImg":"bg-vi","number":"Numbers: 413","value":"vi"},{"cost":"0.00","id":4,"servise":"Telegram","serviseImg":"bg-tg","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"tg"},{"cost":"0.30","id":5,"servise":"WeChat","serviseImg":"bg-wb","number":"Numbers: 28389","value":"wb"},{"cost":"0.15","id":6,"servise":"Google,youtube,Gmail","serviseImg":"bg-go","number":"Numbers: 15419","value":"go"},{"cost":"0.11","id":7,"servise":"avito","serviseImg":"bg-av","number":"Numbers: 17379","value":"av"},{"cost":"0.07","id":8,"servise":"facebook","serviseImg":"bg-fb","number":"Numbers: 21636","value":"fb"},{"cost":"0.03","id":9,"servise":"Twitter","serviseImg":"bg-tw","number":"Numbers: 26864","value":"tw"},{"cost":"0.05","id":10,"servise":"Uber","serviseImg":"bg-ub","number":"Numbers: 20975","value":"ub"},{"cost":"0.22","id":11,"servise":"Qiwi","serviseImg":"bg-qw","number":"Numbers: 20371","value":"qw"},{"cost":"0.02","id":12,"servise":"Gett","serviseImg":"bg-gt","number":"Numbers: 28501","value":"gt"},{"cost":"0.00","id":13,"servise":"OLX","serviseImg":"bg-sn","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"sn"},{"cost":"0.14","id":14,"servise":"Instagram","serviseImg":"bg-ig","number":"Numbers: 3799","value":"ig"},{"cost":"0.00","id":15,"servise":"Hezzl","serviseImg":"bg-ss","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ss"},{"cost":"0.07","id":16,"servise":"\u042e\u043b\u0430","serviseImg":"bg-ym","number":"Numbers: 17597","value":"ym"},{"cost":"0.03","id":17,"servise":"Mail.ru","serviseImg":"bg-ma","number":"Numbers: 17936","value":"ma"},{"cost":"0.03","id":18,"servise":"Microsoft","serviseImg":"bg-mm","number":"Numbers: 3830","value":"mm"},{"cost":"0.03","id":19,"servise":"Airbnb","serviseImg":"bg-uk","number":"Numbers: 28266","value":"uk"},{"cost":"0.00","id":20,"servise":"Line messenger","serviseImg":"bg-me","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"me"},{"cost":"0.03","id":21,"servise":"Yahoo","serviseImg":"bg-mb","number":"Numbers: 19077","value":"mb"},{"cost":"0.00","id":22,"servise":"Drugvokrug.ru","serviseImg":"bg-we","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"we"},{"cost":"0.05","id":23,"servise":"5ka.ru","serviseImg":"bg-bd","number":"Numbers: 27541","value":"bd"},{"cost":"0.00","id":24,"servise":"HQ Trivia","serviseImg":"bg-kp","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"kp"},{"cost":"0.65","id":25,"servise":"Delivery Club","serviseImg":"bg-dt","number":"Numbers: 26812","value":"dt"},{"cost":"0.03","id":26,"servise":"Yandex","serviseImg":"bg-ya","number":"Numbers: 20944","value":"ya"},{"cost":"0.05","id":27,"servise":"Steam","serviseImg":"bg-mt","number":"Numbers: 28121","value":"mt"},{"cost":"0.04","id":28,"servise":"Tinder","serviseImg":"bg-oi","number":"Numbers: 27478","value":"oi"},{"cost":"0.02","id":29,"servise":"Mamba, MeetMe","serviseImg":"bg-fd","number":"Numbers: 25328","value":"fd"},{"cost":"0.00","id":30,"servise":"Dent","serviseImg":"bg-zz","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"zz"},{"cost":"0.07","id":31,"servise":"KakaoTalk","serviseImg":"bg-kt","number":"Numbers: 27823","value":"kt"},{"cost":"0.04","id":32,"servise":"AOL","serviseImg":"bg-pm","number":"Numbers: 23369","value":"pm"},{"cost":"0.02","id":33,"servise":"LinkedIN","serviseImg":"bg-tn","number":"Numbers: 32192","value":"tn"},{"cost":"0.03","id":34,"servise":"Tencent QQ","serviseImg":"bg-qq","number":"Numbers: 27883","value":"qq"},{"cost":"0.06","id":35,"servise":"Magnit","serviseImg":"bg-mg","number":"Numbers: 993","value":"mg"},{"cost":"0.00","id":36,"servise":"pof.com","serviseImg":"bg-pf","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"pf"},{"cost":"0.03","id":37,"servise":"Yalla","serviseImg":"bg-yl","number":"Numbers: 27822","value":"yl"},{"cost":"0.00","id":38,"servise":"kolesa.kz","serviseImg":"bg-kl","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"kl"},{"cost":"0.03","id":39,"servise":"premium.one","serviseImg":"bg-po","number":"Numbers: 25869","value":"po"},{"cost":"0.07","id":40,"servise":"Naver","serviseImg":"bg-nv","number":"Numbers: 27582","value":"nv"},{"cost":"0.03","id":41,"servise":"Netflix","serviseImg":"bg-nf","number":"Numbers: 27715","value":"nf"},{"cost":"0.00","id":42,"servise":"icq","serviseImg":"bg-iq","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"iq"},{"cost":"0.00","id":43,"servise":"Onlinerby","serviseImg":"bg-ob","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ob"},{"cost":"0.00","id":44,"servise":"kufarby","serviseImg":"bg-kb","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"kb"},{"cost":"0.03","id":45,"servise":"Imo","serviseImg":"bg-im","number":"Numbers: 25198","value":"im"},{"cost":"0.00","id":46,"servise":"Michat","serviseImg":"bg-mc","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"mc"},{"cost":"0.03","id":47,"servise":"Discord","serviseImg":"bg-ds","number":"Numbers: 22011","value":"ds"},{"cost":"0.00","id":48,"servise":"Seosprint","serviseImg":"bg-vv","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"vv"},{"cost":"0.00","id":49,"servise":"Monobank","serviseImg":"bg-ji","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ji"},{"cost":"0.03","id":50,"servise":"TikTok\/Douyin","serviseImg":"bg-lf","number":"Numbers: 26299","value":"lf"},{"cost":"0.00","id":51,"servise":"Ukrnet","serviseImg":"bg-hu","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"hu"},{"cost":"0.00","id":52,"servise":"Skout","serviseImg":"bg-wg","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"wg"},{"cost":"0.00","id":53,"servise":"EasyPay","serviseImg":"bg-rz","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"rz"},{"cost":"0.00","id":54,"servise":"Q12 Trivia","serviseImg":"bg-vf","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"vf"},{"cost":"0.00","id":55,"servise":"Pyro Music","serviseImg":"bg-ny","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ny"},{"cost":"0.00","id":56,"servise":"Wolt","serviseImg":"bg-rr","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"rr"},{"cost":"0.00","id":57,"servise":"CliQQ","serviseImg":"bg-fe","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"fe"},{"cost":"0.00","id":58,"servise":"ssoidnet","serviseImg":"bg-la","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"la"},{"cost":"0.00","id":59,"servise":"Zoho","serviseImg":"bg-zh","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"zh"},{"cost":"0.00","id":60,"servise":"Ticketmaster","serviseImg":"bg-gp","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"gp"},{"cost":"0.05","id":61,"servise":"Amazon","serviseImg":"bg-am","number":"Numbers: 25313","value":"am"},{"cost":"0.00","id":62,"servise":"Olacabs","serviseImg":"bg-ly","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ly"},{"cost":"0.00","id":63,"servise":"Rambler","serviseImg":"bg-tc","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"tc"},{"cost":"0.02","id":64,"servise":"ProtonMail","serviseImg":"bg-dp","number":"Numbers: 30668","value":"dp"},{"cost":"0.00","id":65,"servise":"NRJ Music Awards","serviseImg":"bg-pg","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"pg"},{"cost":"0.03","id":66,"servise":"Citymobil","serviseImg":"bg-yf","number":"Numbers: 26997","value":"yf"},{"cost":"0.00","id":67,"servise":"MIRATORG","serviseImg":"bg-op","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"op"},{"cost":"0.03","id":68,"servise":"PGbonus","serviseImg":"bg-fx","number":"Numbers: 27563","value":"fx"},{"cost":"0.03","id":69,"servise":"MEGA","serviseImg":"bg-qr","number":"Numbers: 27848","value":"qr"},{"cost":"0.03","id":70,"servise":"SportMaster","serviseImg":"bg-yk","number":"Numbers: 26584","value":"yk"},{"cost":"0.03","id":71,"servise":"Careem","serviseImg":"bg-ls","number":"Numbers: 27873","value":"ls"},{"cost":"0.03","id":72,"servise":"BIGO LIVE","serviseImg":"bg-bl","number":"Numbers: 25421","value":"bl"},{"cost":"0.03","id":73,"servise":"MyMusicTaste","serviseImg":"bg-mu","number":"Numbers: 27898","value":"mu"},{"cost":"0.03","id":74,"servise":"Snapchat","serviseImg":"bg-fu","number":"Numbers: 27758","value":"fu"},{"cost":"0.00","id":75,"servise":"Keybase","serviseImg":"bg-bf","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"bf"},{"cost":"0.03","id":76,"servise":"OZON","serviseImg":"bg-sg","number":"Numbers: 26595","value":"sg"},{"cost":"0.03","id":77,"servise":"Wildberries","serviseImg":"bg-uu","number":"Numbers: 27220","value":"uu"},{"cost":"0.05","id":78,"servise":"BlaBlaCar","serviseImg":"bg-ua","number":"Numbers: 24367","value":"ua"},{"cost":"0.09","id":79,"servise":"Alibaba","serviseImg":"bg-ab","number":"Numbers: 17818","value":"ab"},{"cost":"0.00","id":80,"servise":"Inboxlv","serviseImg":"bg-iv","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"iv"},{"cost":"0.00","id":81,"servise":"Nttgame","serviseImg":"bg-zy","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"zy"},{"cost":"0.00","id":82,"servise":"Surveytime","serviseImg":"bg-gd","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"gd"},{"cost":"0.00","id":83,"servise":"Mylove","serviseImg":"bg-fy","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"fy"},{"cost":"0.02","id":84,"servise":"mosru","serviseImg":"bg-ce","number":"Numbers: 27173","value":"ce"},{"cost":"0.00","id":85,"servise":"Truecaller","serviseImg":"bg-tl","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"tl"},{"cost":"0.00","id":86,"servise":"Globus","serviseImg":"bg-hm","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"hm"},{"cost":"0.03","id":87,"servise":"Bolt","serviseImg":"bg-tx","number":"Numbers: 27378","value":"tx"},{"cost":"0.00","id":88,"servise":"Shopee","serviseImg":"bg-ka","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ka"},{"cost":"0.03","id":89,"servise":"Perekrestok.ru","serviseImg":"bg-pl","number":"Numbers: 27883","value":"pl"},{"cost":"0.03","id":90,"servise":"Burger King","serviseImg":"bg-ip","number":"Numbers: 27764","value":"ip"},{"cost":"0.00","id":91,"servise":"Prom","serviseImg":"bg-cm","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"cm"},{"cost":"0.03","id":92,"servise":"AliPay","serviseImg":"bg-hw","number":"Numbers: 27166","value":"hw"},{"cost":"0.00","id":93,"servise":"Karusel","serviseImg":"bg-de","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"de"},{"cost":"0.00","id":94,"servise":"IVI","serviseImg":"bg-jc","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"jc"},{"cost":"0.03","id":95,"servise":"inDriver","serviseImg":"bg-rl","number":"Numbers: 27534","value":"rl"},{"cost":"0.03","id":96,"servise":"Happn","serviseImg":"bg-df","number":"Numbers: 27785","value":"df"},{"cost":"0.00","id":97,"servise":"RuTube","serviseImg":"bg-ui","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ui"},{"cost":"0.03","id":98,"servise":"Magnolia","serviseImg":"bg-up","number":"Numbers: 27884","value":"up"},{"cost":"0.03","id":99,"servise":"Foodpanda","serviseImg":"bg-nz","number":"Numbers: 27493","value":"nz"},{"cost":"0.00","id":100,"servise":"Weibo","serviseImg":"bg-kf","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"kf"},{"cost":"0.00","id":101,"servise":"BillMill","serviseImg":"bg-ri","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ri"},{"cost":"0.00","id":102,"servise":"Quipp","serviseImg":"bg-cc","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"cc"},{"cost":"0.00","id":103,"servise":"Okta","serviseImg":"bg-lr","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"lr"},{"cost":"0.03","id":104,"servise":"JDcom","serviseImg":"bg-za","number":"Numbers: 27891","value":"za"},{"cost":"0.05","id":105,"servise":"MTS CashBack","serviseImg":"bg-da","number":"Numbers: 12860","value":"da"},{"cost":"0.00","id":106,"servise":"Fiqsy","serviseImg":"bg-ug","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ug"},{"cost":"0.00","id":107,"servise":"KuCoinPlay","serviseImg":"bg-sq","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"sq"},{"cost":"0.00","id":108,"servise":"Papara","serviseImg":"bg-zr","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"zr"},{"cost":"0.00","id":109,"servise":"Wish","serviseImg":"bg-xv","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"xv"},{"cost":"0.00","id":110,"servise":"Icrypex","serviseImg":"bg-cx","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"cx"},{"cost":"0.00","id":111,"servise":"PaddyPower","serviseImg":"bg-cw","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"cw"},{"cost":"0.05","id":112,"servise":"Baidu","serviseImg":"bg-li","number":"Numbers: 27813","value":"li"},{"cost":"0.00","id":113,"servise":"Dominos Pizza","serviseImg":"bg-dz","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"dz"},{"cost":"0.00","id":114,"servise":"paycell","serviseImg":"bg-xz","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"xz"},{"cost":"0.03","id":115,"servise":"Lenta","serviseImg":"bg-rd","number":"Numbers: 27651","value":"rd"},{"cost":"0.00","id":116,"servise":"Payberry","serviseImg":"bg-qb","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"qb"},{"cost":"0.03","id":117,"servise":"Drom","serviseImg":"bg-hz","number":"Numbers: 27673","value":"hz"},{"cost":"0.00","id":118,"servise":"GlobalTel","serviseImg":"bg-gl","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"gl"},{"cost":"0.00","id":119,"servise":"Deliveroo","serviseImg":"bg-zk","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"zk"},{"cost":"0.00","id":120,"servise":"Socios","serviseImg":"bg-ia","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ia"},{"cost":"0.00","id":121,"servise":"Wmaraci","serviseImg":"bg-xl","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"xl"},{"cost":"0.00","id":122,"servise":"Yemeksepeti","serviseImg":"bg-yi","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"yi"},{"cost":"0.00","id":123,"servise":"Nike","serviseImg":"bg-ew","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ew"},{"cost":"0.02","id":124,"servise":"myGLO","serviseImg":"bg-ae","number":"Numbers: 31671","value":"ae"},{"cost":"0.02","id":125,"servise":"YouStar","serviseImg":"bg-gb","number":"Numbers: 31133","value":"gb"},{"cost":"0.15","id":126,"servise":"\u0420\u0421\u0410","serviseImg":"bg-cy","number":"Numbers: 25178","value":"cy"},{"cost":"0.00","id":127,"servise":"RosaKhutor","serviseImg":"bg-qm","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"qm"},{"cost":"0.00","id":128,"servise":"eBay","serviseImg":"bg-dh","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"dh"},{"cost":"0.00","id":129,"servise":"Pay.kvartplata.ru+","serviseImg":"bg-yb","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"yb"},{"cost":"0.00","id":130,"servise":"GG","serviseImg":"bg-qe","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"qe"},{"cost":"0.03","id":131,"servise":"Grindr","serviseImg":"bg-yw","number":"Numbers: 4841","value":"yw"},{"cost":"0.00","id":132,"servise":"OffGamers","serviseImg":"bg-uz","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"uz"},{"cost":"0.00","id":133,"servise":"Hepsiburadacom","serviseImg":"bg-gx","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"gx"},{"cost":"0.00","id":134,"servise":"Coinbase","serviseImg":"bg-re","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"re"},{"cost":"0.00","id":135,"servise":"RADA NABU","serviseImg":"bg-tj","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"tj"},{"cost":"0.09","id":136,"servise":"PayPal","serviseImg":"bg-ts","number":"Numbers: 27144","value":"ts"},{"cost":"0.00","id":137,"servise":"hily","serviseImg":"bg-rt","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"rt"},{"cost":"0.00","id":138,"servise":"SneakersnStuff","serviseImg":"bg-sf","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"sf"},{"cost":"0.00","id":139,"servise":"Dostavista","serviseImg":"bg-sv","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"sv"},{"cost":"0.00","id":140,"servise":"32red","serviseImg":"bg-qi","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"qi"},{"cost":"0.02","id":141,"servise":"Blizzard","serviseImg":"bg-bz","number":"Numbers: 27797","value":"bz"},{"cost":"0.00","id":142,"servise":"ezbuy","serviseImg":"bg-db","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"db"},{"cost":"0.00","id":143,"servise":"CoinField","serviseImg":"bg-vw","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"vw"},{"cost":"0.00","id":144,"servise":"Airtel","serviseImg":"bg-zl","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"zl"},{"cost":"0.00","id":145,"servise":"Airtel","serviseImg":"bg-wf","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"wf"},{"cost":"0.00","id":146,"servise":"MrGreen","serviseImg":"bg-lw","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"lw"},{"cost":"0.00","id":147,"servise":"Rediffmail","serviseImg":"bg-co","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"co"},{"cost":"0.00","id":148,"servise":"miloan","serviseImg":"bg-ey","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ey"},{"cost":"0.00","id":149,"servise":"Paytm","serviseImg":"bg-ge","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ge"},{"cost":"0.00","id":150,"servise":"Dhani","serviseImg":"bg-os","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"os"},{"cost":"0.00","id":151,"servise":"CMTcuzdan","serviseImg":"bg-ql","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ql"},{"cost":"0.00","id":152,"servise":"Mercado","serviseImg":"bg-cq","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"cq"},{"cost":"0.05","id":153,"servise":"DiDi","serviseImg":"bg-xk","number":"Numbers: 26447","value":"xk"},{"cost":"0.00","id":154,"servise":"Monese","serviseImg":"bg-py","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"py"},{"cost":"0.00","id":155,"servise":"Kotak811","serviseImg":"bg-rv","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"rv"},{"cost":"0.00","id":156,"servise":"Hopi","serviseImg":"bg-jl","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"jl"},{"cost":"0.00","id":157,"servise":"Trendyol","serviseImg":"bg-pr","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"pr"},{"cost":"0.00","id":158,"servise":"Justdating","serviseImg":"bg-pu","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"pu"},{"cost":"0.00","id":159,"servise":"Pairs","serviseImg":"bg-dk","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"dk"},{"cost":"0.00","id":160,"servise":"Touchance","serviseImg":"bg-fm","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"fm"},{"cost":"0.00","id":161,"servise":"SnappFood","serviseImg":"bg-ph","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ph"},{"cost":"0.00","id":162,"servise":"NCsoft","serviseImg":"bg-sw","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"sw"},{"cost":"0.00","id":163,"servise":"Tosla","serviseImg":"bg-nr","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"nr"},{"cost":"0.00","id":164,"servise":"Ininal","serviseImg":"bg-hy","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"hy"},{"cost":"0.00","id":165,"servise":"Paysend","serviseImg":"bg-tr","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"tr"},{"cost":"0.00","id":166,"servise":"CDkeys","serviseImg":"bg-pq","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"pq"},{"cost":"0.00","id":167,"servise":"AVON","serviseImg":"bg-ff","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ff"},{"cost":"0.03","id":168,"servise":"dodopizza","serviseImg":"bg-sd","number":"Numbers: 27739","value":"sd"},{"cost":"0.24","id":169,"servise":"McDonalds","serviseImg":"bg-ry","number":"Numbers: 7729","value":"ry"},{"cost":"0.00","id":170,"servise":"E bike Gewinnspiel","serviseImg":"bg-le","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"le"},{"cost":"0.00","id":171,"servise":"JKF","serviseImg":"bg-hr","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"hr"},{"cost":"0.00","id":172,"servise":"MyFishka","serviseImg":"bg-qa","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"qa"},{"cost":"0.00","id":173,"servise":"Craigslist","serviseImg":"bg-wc","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"wc"},{"cost":"0.00","id":174,"servise":"Foody","serviseImg":"bg-kw","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"kw"},{"cost":"0.00","id":175,"servise":"Grab","serviseImg":"bg-jg","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"jg"},{"cost":"0.05","id":176,"servise":"Zalo","serviseImg":"bg-mj","number":"Numbers: 28606","value":"mj"},{"cost":"0.00","id":177,"servise":"LiveScore","serviseImg":"bg-eu","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"eu"},{"cost":"0.00","id":178,"servise":"888casino","serviseImg":"bg-ll","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ll"},{"cost":"0.00","id":179,"servise":"Gamer","serviseImg":"bg-ed","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ed"},{"cost":"0.00","id":180,"servise":"Huya","serviseImg":"bg-pp","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"pp"},{"cost":"0.00","id":181,"servise":"WestStein","serviseImg":"bg-th","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"th"},{"cost":"0.04","id":182,"servise":"Tango","serviseImg":"bg-xr","number":"Numbers: 27765","value":"xr"},{"cost":"0.00","id":183,"servise":"Global24","serviseImg":"bg-iz","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"iz"},{"cost":"0.03","id":184,"servise":"\u041c\u0412\u0438\u0434\u0435\u043e","serviseImg":"bg-tk","number":"Numbers: 27660","value":"tk"},{"cost":"0.00","id":185,"servise":"Sheerid","serviseImg":"bg-rx","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"rx"},{"cost":"0.00","id":186,"servise":"99app","serviseImg":"bg-ki","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ki"},{"cost":"0.00","id":187,"servise":"CAIXA","serviseImg":"bg-my","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"my"},{"cost":"0.00","id":188,"servise":"OfferUp","serviseImg":"bg-zm","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"zm"},{"cost":"0.00","id":189,"servise":"Swvl","serviseImg":"bg-tq","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"tq"},{"cost":"0.00","id":190,"servise":"Haraj","serviseImg":"bg-au","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"au"},{"cost":"0.00","id":191,"servise":"Taksheel","serviseImg":"bg-ei","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ei"},{"cost":"0.00","id":192,"servise":"hamrahaval","serviseImg":"bg-rp","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"rp"},{"cost":"0.00","id":193,"servise":"Gamekit","serviseImg":"bg-pa","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"pa"},{"cost":"0.00","id":194,"servise":" \u015eikayet var","serviseImg":"bg-fs","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"fs"},{"cost":"0.00","id":195,"servise":"Getir","serviseImg":"bg-ul","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ul"},{"cost":"0.00","id":196,"servise":"irancell","serviseImg":"bg-cf","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"cf"},{"cost":"0.00","id":197,"servise":"Alfa","serviseImg":"bg-bt","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"bt"},{"cost":"0.00","id":198,"servise":"Disney Hotstar","serviseImg":"bg-ud","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ud"},{"cost":"0.00","id":199,"servise":"Agroinform","serviseImg":"bg-qu","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"qu"},{"cost":"0.00","id":200,"servise":"humblebundle","serviseImg":"bg-un","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"un"},{"cost":"0.00","id":201,"servise":"Faberlic","serviseImg":"bg-rm","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"rm"},{"cost":"0.00","id":202,"servise":"CafeBazaar","serviseImg":"bg-uo","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"uo"},{"cost":"0.00","id":203,"servise":"cryptocom","serviseImg":"bg-ti","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ti"},{"cost":"0.00","id":204,"servise":"Gittigidiyor","serviseImg":"bg-nk","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"nk"},{"cost":"0.00","id":205,"servise":"mzadqatar","serviseImg":"bg-jm","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"jm"},{"cost":"0.00","id":206,"servise":"Algida","serviseImg":"bg-lp","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"lp"},{"cost":"0.00","id":207,"servise":"Cita Previa","serviseImg":"bg-si","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"si"},{"cost":"0.00","id":208,"servise":"Potato Chat","serviseImg":"bg-fj","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"fj"},{"cost":"0.00","id":209,"servise":"Bitaqaty","serviseImg":"bg-pt","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"pt"},{"cost":"0.00","id":210,"servise":"Primaries 2020","serviseImg":"bg-qc","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"qc"},{"cost":"0.00","id":211,"servise":"Amasia","serviseImg":"bg-yo","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"yo"},{"cost":"0.00","id":212,"servise":"Dream11","serviseImg":"bg-ve","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ve"},{"cost":"0.00","id":213,"servise":"Oriflame","serviseImg":"bg-qh","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"qh"},{"cost":"0.00","id":214,"servise":"Bykea","serviseImg":"bg-iu","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"iu"},{"cost":"0.00","id":215,"servise":"Immowelt","serviseImg":"bg-ib","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ib"},{"cost":"0.00","id":216,"servise":"Digikala","serviseImg":"bg-zv","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"zv"},{"cost":"0.00","id":217,"servise":"Wing Money","serviseImg":"bg-jb","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"jb"},{"cost":"0.00","id":218,"servise":"Yaay","serviseImg":"bg-vn","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"vn"},{"cost":"0.00","id":219,"servise":"GameArena","serviseImg":"bg-wn","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"wn"},{"cost":"0.04","id":220,"servise":"Vita express","serviseImg":"bg-bj","number":"Numbers: 27861","value":"bj"},{"cost":"0.00","id":221,"servise":"Auchan","serviseImg":"bg-st","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"st"},{"cost":"0.00","id":222,"servise":"Picpay","serviseImg":"bg-ev","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ev"},{"cost":"0.00","id":223,"servise":"Blued","serviseImg":"bg-qn","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"qn"},{"cost":"0.05","id":224,"servise":"Not on the list","serviseImg":"bg-ot","number":"Numbers: 19352","value":"ot"}]
```

The problem is that after my knowledge this is a wrong formatted json file, even if I remove "[" and "]".
I though of just looking at it as a text file to get a specific value but I was unable to find something on the internet about this topic.

I want to get the following value:

**From:**

```
{"cost":"0.00","id":123,"servise":"Nike","serviseImg":"bg-ew","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ew"}
```

**I want to get:**

Numbers: **0**

Comment: That is not a badly formatted json. It is completely fine.

Comment: It's not a wrongly-formatted json file. It's a list of objects, which is valid. Your problem is you are querying the API and it is giving your several values. Even among these there are several with `Numbers: 0`.

Comment: If it were wrongly formatted it wouldnt get parsed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `json.loads` to become a dictionary query:

```py
import requests
import json

response = requests.get('https://sms-service-online.com/api/getServicesAndCost/?country=0&operator=any&lang=en')
data = response.json()
plain = data["data"]
for d in json.loads(plain):
    if d['id'] == 123:
        print(d)
```

Comment: In the line `data = response.json()`, `data` is already a dict - that's what the `.json()` method does. It takes JSON input and returns a dict.

Comment: I know that `data = response.json()` will be json, but `plain = data["data"]` will not be json, try it yourself.  87

Comment: `plain = data["data"]` looks like list[dict, dict], but is actually `str` ok?

Comment: You're absolutely right, I missed that. Weird. (I had to edit your post do undo my downvote)

Answer (score 1):

You have a list of dict in your first example. So first you need to select which dict you want. For instance, if your query is called 'json_list'

```
json_list[2]
```

will get you the third item in that list.

For what you are asking, try:

```
j = {"cost":"0.00","id":123,"servise":"Nike","serviseImg":"bg-ew","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ew"}  
j["number"].split()[-1]
```

Assuming you want to check all numbers in all dict, try:

```
json_list=[{"cost":"0.45","id":0,"servise":"VK.com","serviseImg":"bg-vk","number":"Numbers: 3047","value":"vk"},{"cost":"0.07","id":1,"servise":"OK.ru","serviseImg":"bg-ok","number":"Numbers: 14397","value":"ok"},{"cost":"0.15","id":2,"servise":"Whatsapp","serviseImg":"bg-wa","number":"Numbers: 17610","value":"wa"},{"cost":"0.18","id":3,"servise":"Viber","serviseImg":"bg-vi","number":"Numbers: 413","value":"vi"},{"cost":"0.00","id":4,"servise":"Telegram","serviseImg":"bg-tg","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"tg"},{"cost":"0.30","id":5,"servise":"WeChat","serviseImg":"bg-wb","number":"Numbers: 28389","value":"wb"},{"cost":"0.15","id":6,"servise":"Google,youtube,Gmail","serviseImg":"bg-go","number":"Numbers: 15419","value":"go"},{"cost":"0.11","id":7,"servise":"avito","serviseImg":"bg-av","number":"Numbers: 17379","value":"av"},{"cost":"0.07","id":8,"servise":"facebook","serviseImg":"bg-fb","number":"Numbers: 21636","value":"fb"},{"cost":"0.03","id":9,"servise":"Twitter","serviseImg":"bg-tw","number":"Numbers: 26864","value":"tw"},{"cost":"0.05","id":10,"servise":"Uber","serviseImg":"bg-ub","number":"Numbers: 20975","value":"ub"},{"cost":"0.22","id":11,"servise":"Qiwi","serviseImg":"bg-qw","number":"Numbers: 20371","value":"qw"},{"cost":"0.02","id":12,"servise":"Gett","serviseImg":"bg-gt","number":"Numbers: 28501","value":"gt"},{"cost":"0.00","id":13,"servise":"OLX","serviseImg":"bg-sn","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"sn"},{"cost":"0.14","id":14,"servise":"Instagram","serviseImg":"bg-ig","number":"Numbers: 3799","value":"ig"},{"cost":"0.00","id":15,"servise":"Hezzl","serviseImg":"bg-ss","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ss"},{"cost":"0.07","id":16,"servise":"\u042e\u043b\u0430","serviseImg":"bg-ym","number":"Numbers: 17597","value":"ym"},{"cost":"0.03","id":17,"servise":"Mail.ru","serviseImg":"bg-ma","number":"Numbers: 17936","value":"ma"},{"cost":"0.03","id":18,"servise":"Microsoft","serviseImg":"bg-mm","number":"Numbers: 3830","value":"mm"},{"cost":"0.03","id":19,"servise":"Airbnb","serviseImg":"bg-uk","number":"Numbers: 28266","value":"uk"},{"cost":"0.00","id":20,"servise":"Line messenger","serviseImg":"bg-me","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"me"},{"cost":"0.03","id":21,"servise":"Yahoo","serviseImg":"bg-mb","number":"Numbers: 19077","value":"mb"},{"cost":"0.00","id":22,"servise":"Drugvokrug.ru","serviseImg":"bg-we","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"we"},{"cost":"0.05","id":23,"servise":"5ka.ru","serviseImg":"bg-bd","number":"Numbers: 27541","value":"bd"},{"cost":"0.00","id":24,"servise":"HQ Trivia","serviseImg":"bg-kp","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"kp"},{"cost":"0.65","id":25,"servise":"Delivery Club","serviseImg":"bg-dt","number":"Numbers: 26812","value":"dt"},{"cost":"0.03","id":26,"servise":"Yandex","serviseImg":"bg-ya","number":"Numbers: 20944","value":"ya"},{"cost":"0.05","id":27,"servise":"Steam","serviseImg":"bg-mt","number":"Numbers: 28121","value":"mt"},{"cost":"0.04","id":28,"servise":"Tinder","serviseImg":"bg-oi","number":"Numbers: 27478","value":"oi"},{"cost":"0.02","id":29,"servise":"Mamba, MeetMe","serviseImg":"bg-fd","number":"Numbers: 25328","value":"fd"},{"cost":"0.00","id":30,"servise":"Dent","serviseImg":"bg-zz","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"zz"},{"cost":"0.07","id":31,"servise":"KakaoTalk","serviseImg":"bg-kt","number":"Numbers: 27823","value":"kt"},{"cost":"0.04","id":32,"servise":"AOL","serviseImg":"bg-pm","number":"Numbers: 23369","value":"pm"},{"cost":"0.02","id":33,"servise":"LinkedIN","serviseImg":"bg-tn","number":"Numbers: 32192","value":"tn"},{"cost":"0.03","id":34,"servise":"Tencent QQ","serviseImg":"bg-qq","number":"Numbers: 27883","value":"qq"},{"cost":"0.06","id":35,"servise":"Magnit","serviseImg":"bg-mg","number":"Numbers: 993","value":"mg"},{"cost":"0.00","id":36,"servise":"pof.com","serviseImg":"bg-pf","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"pf"},{"cost":"0.03","id":37,"servise":"Yalla","serviseImg":"bg-yl","number":"Numbers: 27822","value":"yl"},{"cost":"0.00","id":38,"servise":"kolesa.kz","serviseImg":"bg-kl","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"kl"},{"cost":"0.03","id":39,"servise":"premium.one","serviseImg":"bg-po","number":"Numbers: 25869","value":"po"},{"cost":"0.07","id":40,"servise":"Naver","serviseImg":"bg-nv","number":"Numbers: 27582","value":"nv"},{"cost":"0.03","id":41,"servise":"Netflix","serviseImg":"bg-nf","number":"Numbers: 27715","value":"nf"},{"cost":"0.00","id":42,"servise":"icq","serviseImg":"bg-iq","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"iq"},{"cost":"0.00","id":43,"servise":"Onlinerby","serviseImg":"bg-ob","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ob"},{"cost":"0.00","id":44,"servise":"kufarby","serviseImg":"bg-kb","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"kb"},{"cost":"0.03","id":45,"servise":"Imo","serviseImg":"bg-im","number":"Numbers: 25198","value":"im"},{"cost":"0.00","id":46,"servise":"Michat","serviseImg":"bg-mc","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"mc"},{"cost":"0.03","id":47,"servise":"Discord","serviseImg":"bg-ds","number":"Numbers: 22011","value":"ds"},{"cost":"0.00","id":48,"servise":"Seosprint","serviseImg":"bg-vv","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"vv"},{"cost":"0.00","id":49,"servise":"Monobank","serviseImg":"bg-ji","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ji"},{"cost":"0.03","id":50,"servise":"TikTok\/Douyin","serviseImg":"bg-lf","number":"Numbers: 26299","value":"lf"},{"cost":"0.00","id":51,"servise":"Ukrnet","serviseImg":"bg-hu","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"hu"},{"cost":"0.00","id":52,"servise":"Skout","serviseImg":"bg-wg","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"wg"},{"cost":"0.00","id":53,"servise":"EasyPay","serviseImg":"bg-rz","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"rz"},{"cost":"0.00","id":54,"servise":"Q12 Trivia","serviseImg":"bg-vf","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"vf"},{"cost":"0.00","id":55,"servise":"Pyro Music","serviseImg":"bg-ny","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ny"},{"cost":"0.00","id":56,"servise":"Wolt","serviseImg":"bg-rr","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"rr"},{"cost":"0.00","id":57,"servise":"CliQQ","serviseImg":"bg-fe","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"fe"},{"cost":"0.00","id":58,"servise":"ssoidnet","serviseImg":"bg-la","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"la"},{"cost":"0.00","id":59,"servise":"Zoho","serviseImg":"bg-zh","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"zh"},{"cost":"0.00","id":60,"servise":"Ticketmaster","serviseImg":"bg-gp","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"gp"},{"cost":"0.05","id":61,"servise":"Amazon","serviseImg":"bg-am","number":"Numbers: 25313","value":"am"},{"cost":"0.00","id":62,"servise":"Olacabs","serviseImg":"bg-ly","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ly"},{"cost":"0.00","id":63,"servise":"Rambler","serviseImg":"bg-tc","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"tc"},{"cost":"0.02","id":64,"servise":"ProtonMail","serviseImg":"bg-dp","number":"Numbers: 30668","value":"dp"},{"cost":"0.00","id":65,"servise":"NRJ Music Awards","serviseImg":"bg-pg","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"pg"},{"cost":"0.03","id":66,"servise":"Citymobil","serviseImg":"bg-yf","number":"Numbers: 26997","value":"yf"},{"cost":"0.00","id":67,"servise":"MIRATORG","serviseImg":"bg-op","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"op"},{"cost":"0.03","id":68,"servise":"PGbonus","serviseImg":"bg-fx","number":"Numbers: 27563","value":"fx"},{"cost":"0.03","id":69,"servise":"MEGA","serviseImg":"bg-qr","number":"Numbers: 27848","value":"qr"},{"cost":"0.03","id":70,"servise":"SportMaster","serviseImg":"bg-yk","number":"Numbers: 26584","value":"yk"},{"cost":"0.03","id":71,"servise":"Careem","serviseImg":"bg-ls","number":"Numbers: 27873","value":"ls"},{"cost":"0.03","id":72,"servise":"BIGO LIVE","serviseImg":"bg-bl","number":"Numbers: 25421","value":"bl"},{"cost":"0.03","id":73,"servise":"MyMusicTaste","serviseImg":"bg-mu","number":"Numbers: 27898","value":"mu"},{"cost":"0.03","id":74,"servise":"Snapchat","serviseImg":"bg-fu","number":"Numbers: 27758","value":"fu"},{"cost":"0.00","id":75,"servise":"Keybase","serviseImg":"bg-bf","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"bf"},{"cost":"0.03","id":76,"servise":"OZON","serviseImg":"bg-sg","number":"Numbers: 26595","value":"sg"},{"cost":"0.03","id":77,"servise":"Wildberries","serviseImg":"bg-uu","number":"Numbers: 27220","value":"uu"},{"cost":"0.05","id":78,"servise":"BlaBlaCar","serviseImg":"bg-ua","number":"Numbers: 24367","value":"ua"},{"cost":"0.09","id":79,"servise":"Alibaba","serviseImg":"bg-ab","number":"Numbers: 17818","value":"ab"},{"cost":"0.00","id":80,"servise":"Inboxlv","serviseImg":"bg-iv","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"iv"},{"cost":"0.00","id":81,"servise":"Nttgame","serviseImg":"bg-zy","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"zy"},{"cost":"0.00","id":82,"servise":"Surveytime","serviseImg":"bg-gd","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"gd"},{"cost":"0.00","id":83,"servise":"Mylove","serviseImg":"bg-fy","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"fy"},{"cost":"0.02","id":84,"servise":"mosru","serviseImg":"bg-ce","number":"Numbers: 27173","value":"ce"},{"cost":"0.00","id":85,"servise":"Truecaller","serviseImg":"bg-tl","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"tl"},{"cost":"0.00","id":86,"servise":"Globus","serviseImg":"bg-hm","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"hm"},{"cost":"0.03","id":87,"servise":"Bolt","serviseImg":"bg-tx","number":"Numbers: 27378","value":"tx"},{"cost":"0.00","id":88,"servise":"Shopee","serviseImg":"bg-ka","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ka"},{"cost":"0.03","id":89,"servise":"Perekrestok.ru","serviseImg":"bg-pl","number":"Numbers: 27883","value":"pl"},{"cost":"0.03","id":90,"servise":"Burger King","serviseImg":"bg-ip","number":"Numbers: 27764","value":"ip"},{"cost":"0.00","id":91,"servise":"Prom","serviseImg":"bg-cm","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"cm"},{"cost":"0.03","id":92,"servise":"AliPay","serviseImg":"bg-hw","number":"Numbers: 27166","value":"hw"},{"cost":"0.00","id":93,"servise":"Karusel","serviseImg":"bg-de","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"de"},{"cost":"0.00","id":94,"servise":"IVI","serviseImg":"bg-jc","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"jc"},{"cost":"0.03","id":95,"servise":"inDriver","serviseImg":"bg-rl","number":"Numbers: 27534","value":"rl"},{"cost":"0.03","id":96,"servise":"Happn","serviseImg":"bg-df","number":"Numbers: 27785","value":"df"},{"cost":"0.00","id":97,"servise":"RuTube","serviseImg":"bg-ui","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ui"},{"cost":"0.03","id":98,"servise":"Magnolia","serviseImg":"bg-up","number":"Numbers: 27884","value":"up"},{"cost":"0.03","id":99,"servise":"Foodpanda","serviseImg":"bg-nz","number":"Numbers: 27493","value":"nz"},{"cost":"0.00","id":100,"servise":"Weibo","serviseImg":"bg-kf","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"kf"},{"cost":"0.00","id":101,"servise":"BillMill","serviseImg":"bg-ri","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ri"},{"cost":"0.00","id":102,"servise":"Quipp","serviseImg":"bg-cc","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"cc"},{"cost":"0.00","id":103,"servise":"Okta","serviseImg":"bg-lr","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"lr"},{"cost":"0.03","id":104,"servise":"JDcom","serviseImg":"bg-za","number":"Numbers: 27891","value":"za"},{"cost":"0.05","id":105,"servise":"MTS CashBack","serviseImg":"bg-da","number":"Numbers: 12860","value":"da"},{"cost":"0.00","id":106,"servise":"Fiqsy","serviseImg":"bg-ug","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ug"},{"cost":"0.00","id":107,"servise":"KuCoinPlay","serviseImg":"bg-sq","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"sq"},{"cost":"0.00","id":108,"servise":"Papara","serviseImg":"bg-zr","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"zr"},{"cost":"0.00","id":109,"servise":"Wish","serviseImg":"bg-xv","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"xv"},{"cost":"0.00","id":110,"servise":"Icrypex","serviseImg":"bg-cx","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"cx"},{"cost":"0.00","id":111,"servise":"PaddyPower","serviseImg":"bg-cw","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"cw"},{"cost":"0.05","id":112,"servise":"Baidu","serviseImg":"bg-li","number":"Numbers: 27813","value":"li"},{"cost":"0.00","id":113,"servise":"Dominos Pizza","serviseImg":"bg-dz","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"dz"},{"cost":"0.00","id":114,"servise":"paycell","serviseImg":"bg-xz","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"xz"},{"cost":"0.03","id":115,"servise":"Lenta","serviseImg":"bg-rd","number":"Numbers: 27651","value":"rd"},{"cost":"0.00","id":116,"servise":"Payberry","serviseImg":"bg-qb","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"qb"},{"cost":"0.03","id":117,"servise":"Drom","serviseImg":"bg-hz","number":"Numbers: 27673","value":"hz"},{"cost":"0.00","id":118,"servise":"GlobalTel","serviseImg":"bg-gl","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"gl"},{"cost":"0.00","id":119,"servise":"Deliveroo","serviseImg":"bg-zk","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"zk"},{"cost":"0.00","id":120,"servise":"Socios","serviseImg":"bg-ia","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ia"},{"cost":"0.00","id":121,"servise":"Wmaraci","serviseImg":"bg-xl","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"xl"},{"cost":"0.00","id":122,"servise":"Yemeksepeti","serviseImg":"bg-yi","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"yi"},{"cost":"0.00","id":123,"servise":"Nike","serviseImg":"bg-ew","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ew"},{"cost":"0.02","id":124,"servise":"myGLO","serviseImg":"bg-ae","number":"Numbers: 31671","value":"ae"},{"cost":"0.02","id":125,"servise":"YouStar","serviseImg":"bg-gb","number":"Numbers: 31133","value":"gb"},{"cost":"0.15","id":126,"servise":"\u0420\u0421\u0410","serviseImg":"bg-cy","number":"Numbers: 25178","value":"cy"},{"cost":"0.00","id":127,"servise":"RosaKhutor","serviseImg":"bg-qm","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"qm"},{"cost":"0.00","id":128,"servise":"eBay","serviseImg":"bg-dh","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"dh"},{"cost":"0.00","id":129,"servise":"Pay.kvartplata.ru+","serviseImg":"bg-yb","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"yb"},{"cost":"0.00","id":130,"servise":"GG","serviseImg":"bg-qe","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"qe"},{"cost":"0.03","id":131,"servise":"Grindr","serviseImg":"bg-yw","number":"Numbers: 4841","value":"yw"},{"cost":"0.00","id":132,"servise":"OffGamers","serviseImg":"bg-uz","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"uz"},{"cost":"0.00","id":133,"servise":"Hepsiburadacom","serviseImg":"bg-gx","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"gx"},{"cost":"0.00","id":134,"servise":"Coinbase","serviseImg":"bg-re","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"re"},{"cost":"0.00","id":135,"servise":"RADA NABU","serviseImg":"bg-tj","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"tj"},{"cost":"0.09","id":136,"servise":"PayPal","serviseImg":"bg-ts","number":"Numbers: 27144","value":"ts"},{"cost":"0.00","id":137,"servise":"hily","serviseImg":"bg-rt","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"rt"},{"cost":"0.00","id":138,"servise":"SneakersnStuff","serviseImg":"bg-sf","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"sf"},{"cost":"0.00","id":139,"servise":"Dostavista","serviseImg":"bg-sv","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"sv"},{"cost":"0.00","id":140,"servise":"32red","serviseImg":"bg-qi","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"qi"},{"cost":"0.02","id":141,"servise":"Blizzard","serviseImg":"bg-bz","number":"Numbers: 27797","value":"bz"},{"cost":"0.00","id":142,"servise":"ezbuy","serviseImg":"bg-db","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"db"},{"cost":"0.00","id":143,"servise":"CoinField","serviseImg":"bg-vw","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"vw"},{"cost":"0.00","id":144,"servise":"Airtel","serviseImg":"bg-zl","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"zl"},{"cost":"0.00","id":145,"servise":"Airtel","serviseImg":"bg-wf","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"wf"},{"cost":"0.00","id":146,"servise":"MrGreen","serviseImg":"bg-lw","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"lw"},{"cost":"0.00","id":147,"servise":"Rediffmail","serviseImg":"bg-co","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"co"},{"cost":"0.00","id":148,"servise":"miloan","serviseImg":"bg-ey","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ey"},{"cost":"0.00","id":149,"servise":"Paytm","serviseImg":"bg-ge","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ge"},{"cost":"0.00","id":150,"servise":"Dhani","serviseImg":"bg-os","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"os"},{"cost":"0.00","id":151,"servise":"CMTcuzdan","serviseImg":"bg-ql","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ql"},{"cost":"0.00","id":152,"servise":"Mercado","serviseImg":"bg-cq","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"cq"},{"cost":"0.05","id":153,"servise":"DiDi","serviseImg":"bg-xk","number":"Numbers: 26447","value":"xk"},{"cost":"0.00","id":154,"servise":"Monese","serviseImg":"bg-py","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"py"},{"cost":"0.00","id":155,"servise":"Kotak811","serviseImg":"bg-rv","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"rv"},{"cost":"0.00","id":156,"servise":"Hopi","serviseImg":"bg-jl","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"jl"},{"cost":"0.00","id":157,"servise":"Trendyol","serviseImg":"bg-pr","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"pr"},{"cost":"0.00","id":158,"servise":"Justdating","serviseImg":"bg-pu","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"pu"},{"cost":"0.00","id":159,"servise":"Pairs","serviseImg":"bg-dk","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"dk"},{"cost":"0.00","id":160,"servise":"Touchance","serviseImg":"bg-fm","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"fm"},{"cost":"0.00","id":161,"servise":"SnappFood","serviseImg":"bg-ph","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ph"},{"cost":"0.00","id":162,"servise":"NCsoft","serviseImg":"bg-sw","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"sw"},{"cost":"0.00","id":163,"servise":"Tosla","serviseImg":"bg-nr","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"nr"},{"cost":"0.00","id":164,"servise":"Ininal","serviseImg":"bg-hy","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"hy"},{"cost":"0.00","id":165,"servise":"Paysend","serviseImg":"bg-tr","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"tr"},{"cost":"0.00","id":166,"servise":"CDkeys","serviseImg":"bg-pq","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"pq"},{"cost":"0.00","id":167,"servise":"AVON","serviseImg":"bg-ff","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ff"},{"cost":"0.03","id":168,"servise":"dodopizza","serviseImg":"bg-sd","number":"Numbers: 27739","value":"sd"},{"cost":"0.24","id":169,"servise":"McDonalds","serviseImg":"bg-ry","number":"Numbers: 7729","value":"ry"},{"cost":"0.00","id":170,"servise":"E bike Gewinnspiel","serviseImg":"bg-le","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"le"},{"cost":"0.00","id":171,"servise":"JKF","serviseImg":"bg-hr","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"hr"},{"cost":"0.00","id":172,"servise":"MyFishka","serviseImg":"bg-qa","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"qa"},{"cost":"0.00","id":173,"servise":"Craigslist","serviseImg":"bg-wc","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"wc"},{"cost":"0.00","id":174,"servise":"Foody","serviseImg":"bg-kw","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"kw"},{"cost":"0.00","id":175,"servise":"Grab","serviseImg":"bg-jg","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"jg"},{"cost":"0.05","id":176,"servise":"Zalo","serviseImg":"bg-mj","number":"Numbers: 28606","value":"mj"},{"cost":"0.00","id":177,"servise":"LiveScore","serviseImg":"bg-eu","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"eu"},{"cost":"0.00","id":178,"servise":"888casino","serviseImg":"bg-ll","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ll"},{"cost":"0.00","id":179,"servise":"Gamer","serviseImg":"bg-ed","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ed"},{"cost":"0.00","id":180,"servise":"Huya","serviseImg":"bg-pp","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"pp"},{"cost":"0.00","id":181,"servise":"WestStein","serviseImg":"bg-th","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"th"},{"cost":"0.04","id":182,"servise":"Tango","serviseImg":"bg-xr","number":"Numbers: 27765","value":"xr"},{"cost":"0.00","id":183,"servise":"Global24","serviseImg":"bg-iz","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"iz"},{"cost":"0.03","id":184,"servise":"\u041c\u0412\u0438\u0434\u0435\u043e","serviseImg":"bg-tk","number":"Numbers: 27660","value":"tk"},{"cost":"0.00","id":185,"servise":"Sheerid","serviseImg":"bg-rx","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"rx"},{"cost":"0.00","id":186,"servise":"99app","serviseImg":"bg-ki","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ki"},{"cost":"0.00","id":187,"servise":"CAIXA","serviseImg":"bg-my","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"my"},{"cost":"0.00","id":188,"servise":"OfferUp","serviseImg":"bg-zm","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"zm"},{"cost":"0.00","id":189,"servise":"Swvl","serviseImg":"bg-tq","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"tq"},{"cost":"0.00","id":190,"servise":"Haraj","serviseImg":"bg-au","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"au"},{"cost":"0.00","id":191,"servise":"Taksheel","serviseImg":"bg-ei","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ei"},{"cost":"0.00","id":192,"servise":"hamrahaval","serviseImg":"bg-rp","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"rp"},{"cost":"0.00","id":193,"servise":"Gamekit","serviseImg":"bg-pa","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"pa"},{"cost":"0.00","id":194,"servise":" \u015eikayet var","serviseImg":"bg-fs","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"fs"},{"cost":"0.00","id":195,"servise":"Getir","serviseImg":"bg-ul","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ul"},{"cost":"0.00","id":196,"servise":"irancell","serviseImg":"bg-cf","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"cf"},{"cost":"0.00","id":197,"servise":"Alfa","serviseImg":"bg-bt","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"bt"},{"cost":"0.00","id":198,"servise":"Disney Hotstar","serviseImg":"bg-ud","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ud"},{"cost":"0.00","id":199,"servise":"Agroinform","serviseImg":"bg-qu","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"qu"},{"cost":"0.00","id":200,"servise":"humblebundle","serviseImg":"bg-un","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"un"},{"cost":"0.00","id":201,"servise":"Faberlic","serviseImg":"bg-rm","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"rm"},{"cost":"0.00","id":202,"servise":"CafeBazaar","serviseImg":"bg-uo","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"uo"},{"cost":"0.00","id":203,"servise":"cryptocom","serviseImg":"bg-ti","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ti"},{"cost":"0.00","id":204,"servise":"Gittigidiyor","serviseImg":"bg-nk","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"nk"},{"cost":"0.00","id":205,"servise":"mzadqatar","serviseImg":"bg-jm","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"jm"},{"cost":"0.00","id":206,"servise":"Algida","serviseImg":"bg-lp","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"lp"},{"cost":"0.00","id":207,"servise":"Cita Previa","serviseImg":"bg-si","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"si"},{"cost":"0.00","id":208,"servise":"Potato Chat","serviseImg":"bg-fj","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"fj"},{"cost":"0.00","id":209,"servise":"Bitaqaty","serviseImg":"bg-pt","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"pt"},{"cost":"0.00","id":210,"servise":"Primaries 2020","serviseImg":"bg-qc","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"qc"},{"cost":"0.00","id":211,"servise":"Amasia","serviseImg":"bg-yo","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"yo"},{"cost":"0.00","id":212,"servise":"Dream11","serviseImg":"bg-ve","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ve"},{"cost":"0.00","id":213,"servise":"Oriflame","serviseImg":"bg-qh","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"qh"},{"cost":"0.00","id":214,"servise":"Bykea","serviseImg":"bg-iu","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"iu"},{"cost":"0.00","id":215,"servise":"Immowelt","serviseImg":"bg-ib","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ib"},{"cost":"0.00","id":216,"servise":"Digikala","serviseImg":"bg-zv","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"zv"},{"cost":"0.00","id":217,"servise":"Wing Money","serviseImg":"bg-jb","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"jb"},{"cost":"0.00","id":218,"servise":"Yaay","serviseImg":"bg-vn","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"vn"},{"cost":"0.00","id":219,"servise":"GameArena","serviseImg":"bg-wn","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"wn"},{"cost":"0.04","id":220,"servise":"Vita express","serviseImg":"bg-bj","number":"Numbers: 27861","value":"bj"},{"cost":"0.00","id":221,"servise":"Auchan","serviseImg":"bg-st","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"st"},{"cost":"0.00","id":222,"servise":"Picpay","serviseImg":"bg-ev","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"ev"},{"cost":"0.00","id":223,"servise":"Blued","serviseImg":"bg-qn","number":"Numbers: 0","value":"qn"},{"cost":"0.05","id":224,"servise":"Not on the list","serviseImg":"bg-ot","number":"Numbers: 19352","value":"ot"}]
for j in json_list:
    n = i['number'].split()[-1]
    print(n)
    # do something interesting with n
```